# Change text in SVG using react and react-svg-loader

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm using `react-svg-loader` to load my svg files, but want the text in them to be set via react.

React eg:

```
import MyImage from '../img/my_image.svg'

export default class Show extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {text: "show this"} // How do I get this into the SVG?
    }
    render(){
        return (<MyImage />)
    }
}
```

SVG eg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="450">
    <rect
        x="0"
        y="0"
        width="300"
        height="450"
        fill="#d0d0d0"
    />
    <text
        id="textInHere"
        ref="textInHere"
        x="50%"
        y="50%"
        fill="#7d7d7d">
        The text should go here
    </text>
</svg>
```

I can't seem to access the `ref` within react and accessing via `id` is frowned upon.

I'm happy to change my loader if that will make this process easier.

Comment: Is it possible for you to move the SVG dom inside a *new* component's render function. And you can simply use that component and pass value into it via props.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep them separate so they can be edited by external programs and changes can be tracked easily. Some of the SVG are generated and are quite large.